# Excel using SUMIF to calculate totals of multiple columns

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use Excle's SUMIF to calculate totals of `Col1 to Col5` for dates that are similar.

My formula is as follows `=SUMIF($A2:$A7,A10,$B2:$F7)`, but this only gives me the total of a single column.

How can I get the Totals of all the columns based on the date like I've shown in my results.

```
Date        Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5
1/5/2017    1       2       2       
1/5/2017    5                       3       1
1/5/2017    9       5       5       
2/5/2017    10      5       3       
2/5/2017    20                      10      3   
2/5/2017            6       8       1       5
```

Desired Results

```
 1/5/2017   15      7       7       3       1
 2/5/2017   30      11      11      11      8
```

Comment: Your desired results are still summed based on  single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

use below formula in cell B11

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,$A11,B$2:B$7)
```

Comment: This isn't what i'm trying to achieve. See my `Desired Results`

Comment: This isn't an array formula (entered with ctrl+shift, and I am pretty sure an array formula won't work with `SUMIF`, but the formula as provide with the anchors as given, will produce the right results if you put this in B9 and copy it across five and down one. I came up with exactly the same result and was going to post it when I realised it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Per the example you provided, One solution is to use `SUMPRODUCT`

> Multiplies corresponding components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products

[Microsoft Docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) give a thorough example, but per SO etiquette, here is an example in case of link-rot: [FYI, I used absolute reference for easier filling across, arbitrary how you get it done though]

[image]

Forumlas shown:

[image]

Formula is kind of hard to see without clicking on image:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$3:$B$8=$B$11)*C3:C8)
```

This basically breaks down like this, it searches the B:B column for a match, and it will naturally return a true or false for the match, or 0/1 counterparts, and multiplys that by the number found in the column to the right (C3:C8), so it will either be `1 * # = #` or `0 * # = 0`